# Como atualizar o valor de uma celula com base em outra no Grid View WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Eu tenho a seguinte Grid, gostaria de saber como posso fazer para que quando sair do campo Ganho ou Gasto ele atualize o Total?

Caso exista outra forma de fazer fico feliz em conhecer.

Total = (Ganho - Gasto)

```
    private void txtGanho_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtGanho = (TextBox)sender;
        //Aqui eu tenho o valor do Ganho, como posso encontrar na Grid os TextBox com Gasto e Total
    }

    private void txtGasto_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtGasto = (TextBox)sender;
        //Aqui tenho o valor do Gasto, como posso encontrar na Grid os TextBox com Ganho e Total            
    }
```

Arquivo .xaml

```xml
   <DataGrid x:Name="dgControleFinanceiro" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding Data}" IsReadOnly="True"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ganho do dia"  IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Name="txtGanho" Text="{Binding Ganho}" LostFocus="txtGanho_LostFocus"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Gasto do dia"  IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Name="txtGasto" Text="{Binding Gasto}" LostFocus="txtGasto_LostFocus"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Total do dia" IsReadOnly="true">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Name="txtTotal" Text="{Binding Total}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de se fazer isso, é através de uma `ViewModel`. Essa ViewModel deverá implementar a interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`. O `UpdateSourceTrigger` do Binding das propriedades `ValorGanho` e `ValorGasto` precisa ser `LostFocus`, que quando perder o foco, o `set` será executado. Então sempre que acontecer um `set` em `ValorPago` ou `ValorGanho`, a View será notificada da mudança no `Total`, refletindo na grid.

```
public class ControleFinanceiroViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

   protected void NotificarMudancaPropriedade([CallerMemberName] string nomePropriedade = null)
   {
     if (nomePropriedade != null)
     {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nomePropriedade));
     }
   }

   private decimal valorGasto;
   public decimal ValorGasto
   {
     get { return this.valorGasto; }
     set
     {
       this.valorGasto = value;
       this.NotificarMudancaPropriedade();
       this.NotificarMudancaPropridade("Total");
     }
   }

   private decimal valorGanho;
   public decimal ValorGanho
   {
     get { return this.valorGanho; }
     set
     {
       this.valorGanho= value;
       this.NotificarMudancaPropriedade();
       this.NotificarMudancaPropridade("Total");
     }
   }

   public decimal Total 
   {
     get { return this.ValorGanho - this.ValorGasto; }
   }
}
```

O Binding ficará assim da forma abaixo, e você remove o evento `LostFocus`

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Name="txtGanho" Text="{Binding Ganho, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = LostFocus}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Não é uma boa prática em WPF trabalhar com eventos, uma vez que pode trabalhar com MVVM. E recuperar objetos de outra célula da grid em WPF pode ser bem trabalhoso. Então deixo essa abordagem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta @Murilo assim que eu conseguir vou tentar implementar desta forma. Eu não sabia que existia esse MVVM, você conhece algum material para que eu possa aprender? Pois eu programo tudo com eventos.

Comment: Não tenho material especifico. Aprendi com fóruns e tutoriais(via google mesmo); Mas você pode conseguir recuperar seu textbox através da TreeVisual https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx http://www.wpftutorial.net/logicalandvisualtree.html